# How to configure sender mail address in laravel .env file

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel and I want to configure the sender mail address in env and mail.php file.
The thing is that I am not using gmails and I want to use my office email address - example@XXXXX-XXX.co.il

**.env** file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
```

**mail.php** file:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

'from' => [
     'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
     'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
```

What do I need to change in order to send mails?

Comment: Create an entry `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` in your `.env` file and fill it with the correct value? I either don't understand the question or you're thinking way too hard ;)

Comment: Then there's always the [Laravel Mail documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#writing-mailables), with a section on "_Configuring The Sender_"

Comment: `'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),` is telling Laravel to use the environment variable `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` from your `.env` file, if that doesn't exist use `hello@example.com`. Like @Loek said, just add/edit `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` in your .env file, you might need to run `php artisan config:clear` to read in the new value

Comment: Than you all! so if I do not use Gmail and want to use my office email like 'someuser@XXXXX-XXX.co.il' (XXXXX-XXX, is the company name) so i need to change 'MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS' to this and add the same to the env. file?

Answer (score 0):

Edit these lines inside your .env file and then you will be able to use laravel mail function.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xyz@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: Thanks! actually I want to use my office mail like 'someuser@XXXX-XX.co.il' (XXXX-XX is the company name) so I need to change it to 'smtp.someuser@XXXX-XX.co.il'? and I  should not change the mail.php file?